# What's wrong with my Vigenere Cypher CS50

Tags: c, vigenere, cs50

My code for [CS50](https://manual.cs50.net/library/) pset2 Vigenere cypher is as follows. Please help me find the bug. This code basically does nothing when the key includes the letter 'a'. It says "Floating Point Exception". I don't know what that means. Please go through the code and tell me what the bug is.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cs50.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //check if there are only two command line arguments//

    if (argc!=2)
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid input!\n");
        return 1;
    };

    string key = argv[1];

    for(int i=0, n=strlen(key); i < n; i++)
    {
        //check if there is any number in the key//

        if(!isalpha(key[i]))
        {
            printf("Invalid Key!\n");
            return 1;
        };

        //converting the key into ints.//

        if(islower(key[i]))
        {
            key[i] = key[i] - 'a';
        }
        else if(isupper(key[i]))
        {
            key[i] = key[i] - 'A';
        };
    };

    //prompt user for the string//

    string s = GetString();

    int c;
    int k;
    int stln = strlen(s);
    int kyln = strlen(key);          

    for(int j = 0, m = strlen(s); j < m; j++)
    {
        if(islower(s[j]))
        {
            s[j] = s[j] - 'a';

            //for wrapping around the key//

            if(stln > kyln)
            {
                k = j % strlen(key);
                c = (s[j] + key[k]) % 26;
                s[j] = 'a' + c;
            } 
            else
            {
                c = (s[j] + key[j]) % 26;
                s[j] = 'a' + c;
            };
         } 
         else if (isupper(s[j]))
         {
             s[j] = s[j] - 'A';

             //for wrapping around the key//

             k = j % strlen(key);

             if(stln > kyln)
             {
                 c = (s[j] + key[k]) % 26;
                 s[j] = 'A' + c;
             } 
             else
             {
                 c = (s[j] + key[j]) % 26;
                 s[j] = 'A' + c;
             };
         };

    };

    printf("%s\n", s);

};
```

Comment: Show definition of `string`.

Comment: Off topic: you don't need semicolons after closing curly braces. In other words `};` should be `}`

Comment: chux, the cs50 library included defines string.  It is just typedef of char* http://mirror.cs50.net/library50/c/cs50-library-c-3.0/cs50.h

Comment: @MacedonZero Thanks for `typedef char *string;`  For a long time I thought a _string_ was a pointer in C - much like that `typedef`.  Instead C defines a _string_ as an array of characters up to the null character.  That more correct definition solved a lot of problems and improved understanding.  `typedef char *string_ptr;` would be more educational.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strlen(key)` is invalid in later code as earlier code was injecting null characters in `key[]` whenever an `'a'` or `'A'` was used:

```
if(islower(key[i])) {
  key[i] = key[i] - 'a';
```

Find the string length of `key[]` before changing its contents and use that

```
 int n = strlen(key);
 ...
 // k = j % strlen(key);
 k = j % n;
```